# Compare two folders for missing files

Tags: files, filenames

I have two different folders each with the same file names in it but one has missing files. How am I able to compare the two folders `Folder1` and `Folder2` and list the files missing in `Folder2` which `Folder1` contains.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ tree
.
|-- dir1
|   |-- file1
|   |-- file2
|   |-- file3
|   |-- file4
|   `-- file5
`-- dir2
    |-- file2
    |-- file4
    `-- file5

2 directories, 8 files
```

```
$ for f1 in dir1/*; do f2="dir2/${f1#dir1/}"; [ ! -e "$f2" ] && printf '%s\n' "$f2"; done
dir2/file1
dir2/file3
```

This loops through all the names in the first directory, and for each creates the corresponding name of a file expected to exist in the second directory.  If that file does not exist, its name is printed.

The loop, written out more verbosely (and using `basename` rather than a parameter substitution to delete the directory name from the pathname of the files in the first directory):

```sh
for f1 in dir1/*; do
    f2="dir2/$( basename "$f1" )"
    if [ ! -e "$f2" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$f2"
    fi
done
```

---

If the files in the two directories not only have the same names, but also the same contents, you may use `diff` (note: BSD `diff` used here, GNU `diff` may possibly say something else):

```
$ diff dir1 dir2
Only in dir1: file1
Only in dir1: file3
```

If the file contents of files with identical names differ, then this would obviously output quite a lot of additional data that may not be of interest.  `diff -q` may quiet it down a bit in that case.

See also the `diff` manual on your system.

---

For comparing deeper hierarchies, you may want to use `rsync`:

```
$ rsync -r --ignore-existing -i -n dir1/ dir2
>f+++++++++ file1
>f+++++++++ file3
```

The above will output a line for each file anywhere under `dir1` that does not have a corresponding file under `dir2`.  The `-n` option (`--dry-run`) makes sure that no file is actually transferred to `dir2`.

The `-r` option (`--recursive`) makes the operation recursive and `-i` (`--itemize-changes`) selects the particular output format  (the `>f` and the pluses indicates that the file is a new file on the receiving end).

See also the `rsync` manual.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also add how to check two folders based just off the files names? not size.

Comment: @Teddy291 I believe that's what the `rsync` and the first shell loop solution in my answer does.  The `diff` variation will obviously try to look inside files as well.

Comment: The `tree` can be used for quick comparison by number of folders and files of various paths by printing last row of the output: `tree /path/to/dir1 | tail -n 1 ; tree /path/to/dir2 | tail -n 1` will prints `0 directories, 5 files 0 directories, 3 files` BUT keep on mind that it is just a number of folders or files so there might be same number of files with different names or content!