# How to compare the ls output of two folders to find a missing directory?

Tags: files

I'm trying to compare a folder with 1400 subfolders to one with a 1.399. I need to know which subfolder is missing.

I tried this:

```
diff -rq dir1/ dir2/ | grep dir1/ | awk '{print $4}' > difference1.txt
```

But it's been like 6 hours yet and no output. `ls` in the folders is nearly instant so is there a faster approach than diff?

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997693/given-two-directory-trees-how-can-i-find-out-which-files-differ

Comment: @GMaster I'm asking for a faster approach

Comment: Sounds similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/524074/117549

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
diff -u <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
```

This will make sure `diff` does not look inside the subdirs.

Or try this if you are brave ;)

```bsh
diff -u <(find dir1/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;) <(find dir2/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {} \;)
```

Comment: `diff -u <(cd dir1; find -type d | sort) <(cd dir2; find -type d | sort)` ?

Comment: =) ............

Comment: `comm -23 <(ls /dir1 |sort) <(ls /dir2 |sort)` also worked for me and was very fast too

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly simple task for `rsync`.

`rsync -n -av dir1/ dir2/ | grep '/$' | grep -Fvx './'`

This does a dry run of `rsync`ing `dir1`'s contents into `dir2`, and displays only the lines ending in a slash (the directories), except possibly for the top-level directory itself.

Here's a simple test/demo:

```
$ # create 1500 folders in dir1:
$ for i in $(jot -w %04d 1500); do mkdir -p dir1/dir-$i; done
$ # clone dir1 to dir2, then remove one directory:
$ rsync -a dir1/ dir2/
$ rmdir dir2/dir-0749/
$ # rsync -n will tell you which one is missing:
$ time rsync -n -av dir1/ dir2/ | grep '/$' | grep -Fvx './'
dir-0749/

real    0m0.038s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.041s
```

If you would like to adapt this technique to also check for folders missing from `dir1` but present in `dir2`, use `rsync`'s `--delete` option:

```
$ rmdir dir1/dir-0479/
$ time rsync -nav --delete dir1/ dir2/ | grep '/$' | grep -Fvx './'
deleting dir-0479/
dir-0749/
```

The `deleting ...` line tells you that `dir-0479` is absent from `dir1` but present in `dir2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try either
`ls dir1 > file1; ls dir2 > file2; diff file1 file2`

or if you have vimdiff and tree which is the most useful way with sub directories, you could use

`tree dir1 > file1; tree dir2 > fiel2; vimdiff file1 file2`

Though, running ls is much faster than tree which is what you are after.

If the difference is in a sub-directory in dir1 
eg.

```
dir1
 - dir2
 - dir3
    - dir4
vs

dir2
 - dir2
 - dir3
```

You would need to do

`ls -R dir1 > file1; ls -R dir2 > file2; vimdiff file1 file2`

Comment: This would try to compare names of non-directories too, of which we know nothing about.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT]  After posting I noticed @freedo already mentioned `comm` before me. [/EDIT]

First store lists of the directory trees into files:

```
# Using parenthesis ensures the command are executed inside a subshell, so
# changing directory (`cd`) back afterwards is not needed.

(cd dir1 ; find -type d | sort >/tmp/list1)
(cd dir2 ; find -type d | sort >/tmp/list2)
```

Then this command will show what's present in `dir1` but not in `dir2`:

```
comm -23 /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2
```

While this commmand will show what is in `dir2` but not in `dir1`:

```
comm -13 /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2
```

And this will show what is present in both:

```
comm -12 /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2
```

Finally, this will show all information above at once, in 3 columns:

```
comm /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2
```

The `comm` utility seems not be very well known.  But it's probably installed by default on most if not all Linux systems. In Debian it's in the "coreutils" package, which is marked "essential".

Little known command, but `comm` proved **very useful** to me once, while I was solving nasty problems in a big filesystem (> 25 Tb). I feel I owe it to `comm` to advocate its use.

Answer (score -1):

diff <(tree -d dir_A) <(tree -d dir_B)